# C memory layout for two dimensional string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I'm trying to figure out how the memory layout for two dimensional arrays in c works. Especially arrays of strings. I know how it should work after reading [this site](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html)

But when doing allocation like

```
char *states[] = {
    "California", "Oregon",
    "Washington", "Texas"
};
```

is the row size automatically set to match the size of the longest string?

I've tried to figure it out using the following code but I still don't get it.

```
int main(){
  char *test[] = {
    "0", "12",
    "345", "6789"
  };
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  for (i=0; i<10; i++){
   for (j=0; j<10; j++){
     printf("%d,%d: ", i,j);
     printf("%c\n", test[i][j]);
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I have the feeling that all the rows should have the same size but seems like the next string starts immediately after a single white space when traversing through the array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have a 2-dimensional `char` array. Instead, you have a 1-dimensional array of `char` pointers. In a 2-dimensional `char` array, all of the strings would have the exact same amount of memory allocated for them. Your case is actually simpler in a lot of ways. The compiler creates a bunch of constant strings, and initializes your char * array with those pointers. Each string has its own independent length.

Here's how you'd declare a true 2-dimensional `char` array:

```
char states[][11] = {
    "California",
    "Oregon",
    "Washington",
    "Texas"
};
```

Here the string length is explicit (10 characters maximum, plus 1 for the null byte).  Each string is given the full number of characters, whether it uses them all or not.